# Possible causes for an intermittent IOException error?

Tags: java, blazegraph, openrdf

I am attempting to write to a Blazegraph database file multiple times using the OpenRDF Java API. Here is some pseudocode that mimics what I'm trying to do:

```
//create Connection to the database
Repository repo = new Repository("database.jnl")
RepositoryConnection cxn = newConnection(repo)
cxn.add(someData)
cxn.close()
repo.shutDown()
```

Now file *database.jnl* is still there, and I want to repeat the process above, using a new `RepositoryConnection` object on the same file. This works about 50-55% of the time, but often I receive an error:

> java.io.IOException: Stream Closed

I'm wondering what could be the possible cause of an intermittent `IOException`? It is strange to me that it does not occur either all or none of the time.

Comment: Check to make sure the connection is actually established before adding data and closing the connection, perhaps: `if (cnx != null) { ...... }`.

Comment: Does this exception have a stack trace or any other information? Is it a one-liner?